# Disadvantages of representing VAR(p) process as VAR(1) process (vector autoregression)

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

It is obvious that representation of VAR(p) process as VAR(1) process has a couple of advantages:

- This representation(VAR(1)) is much more compact
- Easy to check if process is stable (only looking at eigenvalues of $A_1$)

But my question is: are there any disadvantages of representing VAR(p) process as VAR(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tradeoff between dimensionality and lag order:

- in VAR($p$) you have a potentially high lag order $p$ but low dimensionality (the number of time series) $K$;
- in the corresponding VAR($1$) (the companion form) you have low lag order $1$ but potentially high dimensionality $p\times K$.

Sometimes manipulating $p$ small coefficient matrices of size $K\times K$ can be easier than manipulating one large matrix of size $pK\times pK$.

Also, it is more natural to think about VAR($p$) than the companion VAR($1$). It is no coincidence that the companion form is only introduced in textbooks when it is needed for proofs, but not for general exposition.

Comment: @DanielYefimov, you are welcome! There could also be other nuances, but these were the obvious ones for me.

Comment: Great answer. Also not that VAR is usually applied to small macreconomic datasets. Therefore including too many lags may not be appropriate.

Comment: @Ferdi, thanks! I think the dataset size and lag order are only partly relevant here as we are considering two representations of the same model. Thus a $pK$-dimensional VAR(1) is still the same model as the $K$-dimensional VAR(p). Therefore, the VAR(p) is neither more nor less appropriate than its companion VAR(1) for any given data sample.